# What layer should model resolver be in MVC

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, model, controller

Assume that `MVC` design pattern is using and the `web framework` which is used does not support model resolving from HTTP request(JSON or XML data.). It is required to resolve incoming dumped request data into model object. Now, We need to develop our `model resolver`.

I know that only handling `HTTP` requests on `view layer` and doing all bussiness jobs in `Service(Controller) layer` are right ways for `MVC`. According to this assumption doing model resolving operation in View layer is not good idea. It should be defined in service layer. (Am I wrong?). But so many web frameworks handling it in view layer. The question is, what would be the best way not to break `MVC design pattern` and Why?

Thank You!

## Edited:

I wanna be more specific about model resolving for a webframework which is doing it in view;

Assume client side is asking "Adding a User".

1.) It sends the user data over HTTP and assume it is JSON

2.) Your view layer is handling it, resolving the user JSON data to your User model object(model resolver) and sending the user to service layer(here controller layer starts to work)

3.) Your service layer validating the user.(validation email,username etc.). It is done in here, because it is a bussiness job and it sends to user to model layer to persist.

4.) Your model layer store the user.

This model resolving which is done in view layer is most common in webframeworks as seen in 2.

Comment: This makes no sense. Controllers are not services. Controllers are part of presentation layer, while services are part of model layer. The incoming HTTP request should be interpreted and abstracted long before you even hit the MVC triad. And what is "model resolving"? Why would model layer care about whether you want to present the response as XML or JSON?

Comment: Model layer does not care about request data I didn't say like that in my question. I edited the question to be more specific about model resolving operation please check it.

Answer (score 0):

From my subjective point of view, I don't see any problem with the design or if it violates the SRP. If no logic is needed, the conversion can be handled in any layer. However, if you insist that if the conversion must be held in service layer, then you can also do it. But let me explain why it is not needed. For example (in C#), you has a converter (or resolver):

```
public class UserModelConverter{
    public UserModel FromJSON(string json){
        // parse the JSON and return the class
    }
}
```

Now you has the resolver at service layer, and now you can use a uniform JSON format for user. However, think about some scenario:

1. Say that the UserModel has a `LastName` field. That field is not mandatory, so it may be null. However, you need specific default value for some view (example in Display User screen, you need to set the default value as "[LAST_NAME]", but string.Empty or "-" in other field. You will get difficulty to handle it using the converter, especially in JSON format.
2. In a specific situation, you are forced to use different JSON format for the data. The example can be if the `UserModel` data is a field of another object in screen. How can you maintain it?
3. Normally, especially in MVC, the data are posted to the controller by using form, resulting in each string field. Will you handle the object creation in service layer too? If not, then you are put the creation logic in different layers.

There are also some situations where the resolver is suitable to put in service layer. That may be:

1. Part of the process, such as reading a set of records from CSV or XML.
2. (They may be more, I just not yet found the situation)

If the operation does not contain specific logic (business logic to be precise), do not put it in service layer.